# Count Deaths in multiplayer game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a multiplayer game using photon and I want my player deaths to be count every time is killed. I used this script but I didn't add any photonView.IsMine because every time my player dies , the text from canvas remain : Deaths:0 . The script I used for deaths is this

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon;
using Photon.Pun;




public class DeathsCount : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text countText;
    
    public int deathcount;



     void Start()
    {
        countText = GetComponent<Text>();

        deathcount = 0;
            CmdDeathsCount();
       
    }
    void CmdDeathsCount()
    {
       
        countText.text = "Death: " + deathcount.ToString();
    }

   void  CmdSetDeathsCount(int newCount)
    {
        deathcount = newCount;
    }
    public void RpcRespawn()
    {
        Debug.Log(deathcount);

            deathcount = deathcount + 1;
            CmdDeathsCount();
        
    }
}
```

and the function in my character script I used for damage the player and death :

```css
   [PunRPC]
    void Damage()
    {
        Debug.Log("I damaged");

        Health -= 20;
        if (Health <= 0) // check health status
        {
            Health = 0; // make that Heath don't be < 0

            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                myCounts.RpcRespawn(); //Here you should to call counter
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a method to simply increase the death count in deathcount,  and to call it when death is determined.

```
void IncreaseDeathsCount()
{

    deathcount++;
    CmdDeathsCount()
}
```

```css
[PunRPC]
    void Damage()
    {
        Debug.Log("I damaged");

        Health -= 20;
        if (Health <= 0) // check health status
        {
            Health = 0; // make that Heath don't be < 0

            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                myCounts.RpcRespawn(); //Here you should to call counter
                DeathsCount.cmdDeathsCount;
            }
        }

    }
```

However you will either have to make cmdDeathsCount a static or add a reference to your instance to be able to call it